# Bash script to extract directory which contains file with particular extension

Tags: bash, recursion, directory

So I have a following file structure

```
1. X
   |-a.txt
   |-E
     |- b.txt
   |-B
     |-C
     |-D
       |-c.txt
```

So I want to write a bash script which recursively travels to all subdirectories and echos the path which contains atleast 1 file with extension txt. Hence the output of the script for above example should be `X` (because it contains a.txt), `X/E` (because it contains b.txt) and `X/B/D.`

One more example.

```
2.Y
  |-A
  |-B
    |-c.png
    |-C
      |-D
        |-a.txt
  |-E
    |-b.txt
```

Expected output:- Y/E, Y/B/C/D

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: try. find Y -type d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU find:

```
find Y -type f -name "*.txt" -printf "%h\0" | sort -zu | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Output:

```
Y/B/C/D
Y/E
```

---

See: `man find`

Comment: Isn't it "d" for -type?

Comment: I want to find files and output only its path (`%h`).